# Parse additional fields Struc from JSON into separate columns in Pyspark

Tags: json, parsing, pyspark

I have a JSON file with a field named "AdditionalFields" as below-
"additionalFields":

```
[
   {
      "fieldName":"customer_name",
      "fieldValue":"ABC"
   },
   {
      "fieldName":"deviceid",
      "fieldValue":"1234"
   },
   {
      "fieldName":"txn_id",
      "fieldValue":"2"
   },
   {
      "fieldName":"txn_date",
      "fieldValue":"2017-08-14T18:17:37"
   },
   {
      "fieldName":"orderid",
      "fieldValue":"I126101"
   }
]
```

How to parse this as separate columns? eg customer name to be a column and ABC should be the value.

Tried to parse this as an ArrayType but getting multiple rows for columns "FieldName" and "FieldValue".
Want to get each item under FieldName to be a column & FieldValue to be the respective column value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your JSON, you can also open it using the `json` library and create the DataFrame data by working on the dictionaries:

```py
# Assuming you can load the data using the json python library.
data = [
    {"fieldName": "customer_name", "fieldValue": "ABC"},
    {"fieldName": "deviceid", "fieldValue": "1234"},
    {"fieldName": "txn_id", "fieldValue": "2"},
    {"fieldName": "txn_date", "fieldValue": "2017-08-14T18:17:37"},
    {"fieldName": "orderid", "fieldValue": "I126101"},
]

df_data = [{d["fieldName"]: d["fieldValue"]} for d in data]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_data)
```

Comment: like the use of list comprehension!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is how your sample data looks like:

```
[
{"fieldName":"customer_name","fieldValue":"ABC"},
{"fieldName":"deviceid","fieldValue":"1234"},
{"fieldName":"txn_id","fieldValue":"2"},
{"fieldName":"txn_date","fieldValue":"2017-08-14T18:17:37"},
{"fieldName":"orderid","fieldValue":"I126101"}
]
```

1. Read the sample JSON file using Spark read method

```
df=spark.read.options(multiLine=True).json("path/to/sample.json")
```

2. This function extracts data column wise

```
def return_result(df, column):
    return df.select(column).rdd.map(lambda row: row[f"{column}"]).collect()
```

3. Using the above function on all the columns

```
records = [return_result(df, field) for field in df.columns]
```

This is how it looks like:

```
[['customer_name', 'deviceid', 'txn_id', 'txn_date', 'orderid'], ['ABC', '1234', '2', '2017-08-14T18:17:37', 'I126101']]
```

4. The first record is the header, and the rest of them are data

```
columns, data = records[0], records[1:]
```

5. Use the colelcted and create a DataFrame out of it

```
converted_df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(columns)
converted_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------+------+-------------------+-------+
|customer_name|deviceid|txn_id|           txn_date|orderid|
+-------------+--------+------+-------------------+-------+
|          ABC|    1234|     2|2017-08-14T18:17:37|I126101|
+-------------+--------+------+-------------------+-------+
```